# Not getting notifications when selecting myself as pull request author in the filter

Tags: azure-devops

I'm having trouble to make azure notifications send email notification when someone is commenting on my PR.

In my organization by default notifications are turned off so I'm trying to set it up myself.

I know that the emails are going through because if I select <> in the filter for the author I do get notifications on all PRs doesn't matter who the author is.

The problem is: I don't know what should be provided as value for Pull request author for myself so I can get the emails only on PRs pushed by myself. What I've tried is using basically my account name in azure devops filter. But since that doesn't work I'm guessing something else is used ? Just not sure what.

Below is the screen of the setup I'm trying to use. After '=' there is my account name I use to log in to the system.

[image]

*Edit (image of organization settings. In project settings there is nothing set for comments for pull requests):*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it to work. The filter works by using a Full Name not account name. Which is really weird because Full Name can be actually edited in Azure devops. So from my perspective this is a bug or bad design on Azure devops teams part.

So if anybody else has this issue instead of typing account name: john.kowalski@xx.com you need to use Full Name from profile: ie. John Kowalski.

Edit: I haven't tried it but also using [Me] keyword could work